# Rails + Capybara: clicking link with evaluate_script freezes webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I run the following in my `js: true` request spec:

```
page.evaluate_script("$('#sign-up').click();")
```

That opens the modal successfully. However, the webdriver freezes at that point, regardless of what comes next in the spec. After a long pause, I get:

```
 Failure/Error: 
 Timeout::Error:
   Timeout::Error
 # ./spec/requests/my_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I want to use `evaluate_script` instead of 'click_on' in this case, because there is no `href` attribute on that particular link (click_on doesn't work). How do I get it to work without timing out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to a bug in Selenium.  Found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-capybara/YcZwyPdMJFU

It doesn't hang when replacing `page.evaluate_script` with:

```
page.driver.browser.execute_script
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue for me as well with capybara (1.1.2) and selenium-webdriver (2.25.0). I was actually triggering a mouseover, but had the same Timeout issue.

Comment: You can use `page.execute_script`. No need to go to `page.driver.browser`